# Extract .7z's recursively by name - P7zip

Tags: linux, bash, recursion, compression, 7zip

I have multiple directories, with .7z's inside each, but also other directories inside the same start directory which I do not want to extract. The ones I do want to extract all have a common name, for example: each directory has the word "extract" in it. How could I recursively extract each .7z to a chosen folder that contains the word "extract" in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you should use is:

```
  find . -name "*extract*.7z" -print -exec 7z x {} \;
```

I would have run the command withtout *-exec* before, just to make sure these are the files you would actually like to extract:

```
   find . -name "*extract*.7z" -print
```